# SQL query find for how many days are there blog entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to come up with a way to query my blog database to find out which days within a certain range have posts.

Eg. If my dates are 1/1/2012 - 1/30/2012, how many of those 30 days contain at least one blog post?

My dates are stored as: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just to get the number of days that have posts

```
  SELECT Count(distinct DATE(date_column))
  FROM your_table
  WHERE DATE_COLUMN > '2012-01-01' and DATE_COLUMN < '2012-02-01'
```

To get a list of them, something more like what jergen wrote:

```
 SELECT date(date_column)
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY date(date_column)
```

date is a mysql function to get the date from a datetime column (I haven't tried this, just from reading the manuals)

Comment: The first one did exactly what I wanted when I replaced the WHERE date stuff with sujal's BETWEEN code.  Thanks a lot!  My head was running in circles trying to figure out how I'd do this.

Comment: @Adam, So I should edit my answer to say "WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN 2012-01-01 and 2012-02-01", is that right?  I don't know why it wouldn't work (unless what you copied was before I edited it, I had put dates in wrong format when I first posted)

Comment: yup! exactly.  Not sure why either, but I think the between makes a little more sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(date_column)
from your_table
where date_column between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-30'
group by date_column
having count(date_column) > 0
```

Comment: Should probably add a `having count(date_column) > 0`.

Comment: Why do we need the `having count(date_column) > 0`? I think that all rows generated by the above query will have a count of at least 1. Could you please provide some example data where it can be 0?

Comment: If his dates are stored as 0000-00-00 00:00:00, aren't they datetimes?  So if there are 90 posts on Jan 15, each with a different value in date_column, you're going to get at least 90 recods, right?

Comment: @nikhil500: You may be right, anytime I've done a group by like this where an amount is required, I've always just added the having for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `table_name` 
where 
    mydate>='2011-03-17 06:42:10' and mydate<='2011-03-17 06:42:50';
```

or use between

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `table_name` 
where 
    mydate between '2011-03-17 06:42:10' and '2011-03-17 06:42:50';
```

Comment: aren't you going to get a count of posts, when OP wants count of days with posts?